# Loading large variable from file into dockerfile run

Tags: docker, sed, kibana

I have a large b64 encoded string I want to use in my dockerfile. Since there is a limit for the size of a dockerfile my first approach (having that string directly in my dockerfile) was unsuccessful.

Basically I want to replace a logo svg in base64 encoding inline with sed. Take a look at my dockerfile:

```
FROM docker.elastic.co/kibana/kibana:7.3.1

# custom favicons
COPY favicons/* /usr/share/kibana/src/legacy/ui/public/assets/favicons/
COPY logo_small.svg /usr/share/kibana/node_modules/@elastic/eui/src/components/icon/assets/logo_kibana.svg
COPY logo_small.svg /usr/share/kibana/node_modules/@elastic/eui/lib/components/icon/assets/logo_kibana.svg

# custom throbber
RUN sed -i 's/Loading Kibana/Loading New Kibana/g' /usr/share/kibana/src/legacy/ui/ui_render/views/ui_app.pug

# NOT WORKING inline replacement and variable definition
COPY logo.b64.txt /tmp/logo.b64.txt
RUN export VAR=$(cat /tmp/logo.b64.txt); sed -i 's/image\/svg+xml.*");/image\/svg+xml;base64,$VAR");/g' /usr/share/kibana/src/legacy/ui/ui_render/views/ui_app.pug /usr/share/kibana/src/legacy/ui/ui_render/views/chrome.pug
```

This results in a

> cat: /tmp/logo.b64.txt: No such file or directory

and I have no clue how to fix this.
Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: What is the docker version? Which command you are using for docker build?

Comment: To build I use: `docker build -t kibana-custom-new .` and my Docker-Version is 18.09.7 // Dockerfile Version: 2

Comment: My docker version is 1.13.1 and your dockerfile is built successfully. I am hoping you put logo.b64.txt and dockerfile in the same location. 

Step 4/4 : RUN export VAR=$(cat /tmp/logo.b64.txt); sed -i 's/image\/svg+xml.*");/image\/svg+xml;base64,$VAR");/g' /usr/share/kibana/src/legacy/ui/ui_render/views/ui_app.pug /usr/share/kibana/src/legacy/ui/ui_render/views/chrome.pug
 ---> Using cache
 ---> c2f90a8fea5c
Successfully built c2f90a8fea5c